# How to set base_fee and len_fee to zero?

Tags: polkadot, rust, fee, feeless

I was trying to modify the transaction fee and for that I only want the congestion of the network. In *FeeDetails*, that is present in the **transaction-payment** pallet, we have three fields, i.e., **base_fee, len_fee, adjusted_weight_fee**. The congestion of the network depends on adjusted_weight_fee, so for this purpose I only want that field. But I don't know how to set the other two fields to zero. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`len_fee` is controlled by the `TransactionByteFee`. This `TransactionByteFee` is an associated type of the `transaction-payment` `Config` trait. If you set this to `0`, the `len_fee` is `0`.

The `base_fee` depends on the `base_extrinsic` weight. This weight is then converted to the `base_fee`. You control the `base_extrinsic` weight by the `BlockWeights` associated type. You need to change this type to have a `base_extrinsic` weight for every transaction class and then you always have a `base_fee` of `0`. In the "default" Substrate runtime this type is for example constructed [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L174-L191) and then assigned [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/36b8970ef68b2f8d031f0aeadbe47d06a2679332/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L198) as type `BlockWeights`.

Comment: could you give an example on how to set base_fee ?

Comment: in your links above, it seems the base_fee is fixed for ALL users. But I need to set it only for selected users. How to do it?

Comment: You only want to have the base fee for some users? Why?

Comment: why? my boss told me so... I have a storage in a pallet to check which user can do x number of times feeless transactions. any advice?