# Frontier: How to change EVM gas fee charged in calling precompile functions

Tags: frontier, evm, feeless, precompile

Regarding the EVM gas fee used for calling precompile functions, how can I set that fee to zero so that the MetaMask will show zero fee at invoking those precompile functions?

I saw a demonstration of that zero gas transaction from Moombeam's tutorial https://youtu.be/V9KfvhoqLJ4?t=5348 and its original code is here https://github.com/PureStake/substrate-node-template/commit/142fe9a5ca9ca787925d3bd51c55db44caf444cd

But that video was posted about 1 year ago, so now the code has changed quite a lot...

I can achieve zero fee on MetaMask as the video above did by setting FixedGasPrice and GasWeightMapping below to return zeros in pallet_evm::Config:

```
impl pallet_evm::Config for Runtime {
  type FeeCalculator = FixedGasPrice;
  type GasWeightMapping = GasWeightMapping;
  ...
}
```

BUT that makes ALL transactions gasless! Not good. And in my parachain, that makes such feeless transactions not to be accepted by the validators somehow...

Here is Moonbeam recent code on precompile https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/blob/v0.26.0/precompiles/balances-erc20/src/lib.rs

My file structure:

```
project/precompiles
|- balances-erc20 -> src/lib.rs
|- utils -> src/lib.rs
```

From Parallel Finance's `transfer()` function in  precompiles/balances-erc20/src/lib.rs:

```rust
fn transfer(handle: &mut impl PrecompileHandle) -> EvmResult<PrecompileOutput> {
    handle.record_log_costs_manual(3, 32)?;

    // Parse input.
    let mut input = handle.read_input()?;
    input.expect_arguments(2)?;

    let to: H160 = input.read::<Address>()?.into();
    let amount: U256 = input.read()?;

    // Build call with origin.
    {
        let origin = Runtime::AddressMapping::into_account_id(handle.context().caller);
        let to = Runtime::AddressMapping::into_account_id(to);
        let amount = Self::u256_to_amount(amount)?;

        // Dispatch call (if enough gas).
        RuntimeHelper::<Runtime>::try_dispatch(
            handle,
            Some(origin).into(),
            pallet_balances::Call::<Runtime, Instance>::transfer {
                dest: Runtime::Lookup::unlookup(to),
                value: amount,
            },
        )?;
    }

    LogsBuilder::new(handle.context().address)
        .log3(
            SELECTOR_LOG_TRANSFER,
            handle.context().caller,
            to,
            EvmDataWriter::new().write(amount).build(),
        )
        .record(handle)?;

    // Build output.
    Ok(succeed(EvmDataWriter::new().write(true).build()))
}
```

I found out this `RuntimeHelper::<Runtime>::try_dispatch()` function was imported from my precompiles/utils/src/lib.rs:

inside try_dispatch() in precompiles/utils/src/lib.rs ... see https://github.com/parallel-finance/parallel/blob/master/precompiles/utils/src/lib.rs#L171:

```rust
pub fn try_dispatch<Call>(...){
  let call = Runtime::Call::from(call);
  let dispatch_info = call.get_dispatch_info();

  let required_gas = Runtime::GasWeightMapping::weight_to_gas(dispatch_info.weight);

  let used_weight = call.dispatch(origin)
      .map_err(|e| revert(alloc::format!("Dispatched call failed with error: {:?}", e)))?
      .actual_weight;
```

so I tried to set that required_gas to 0 in my precompiles/balances-erc20/src/lib.rs:

```rust
let mut call = pallet_balances::Call::<Runtime, Instance>::transfer {
   dest: Runtime::Lookup::unlookup(to),
   value: amount,
};
call.get_dispatch_info().weight= 0;

RuntimeHelper::<Runtime>::try_dispatch(
   handle,
   Some(origin).into(),
   call,
)?;
```

But that does not change the gas fee!??

This post talks briefly about base_fee but not very clear on how to do it... [How to set base_fee and len_fee to zero?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/281/how-to-set-base-fee-and-len-fee-to-zero)

And docs talking about base fee and length fee, etc... https://docs.substrate.io/build/tx-weights-fees/

Now, I have made a simple `feeless_transfer()` function from the above `transfer()` function. And my `feeless_transfer()` calls another `feeless_transfer()` that is in my pallet.

This `Ok(Pays::No.into())` in the pallet functions will make the `actual_weight` to become `None` inside `precompiles/utils/src/lib.rs: dispatch()`:

```rust
let actual_weight = call
            .dispatch(origin)
            .map_err(|e| revert(alloc::format!("Dispatched call failed with error: {:?}", e)))?
            .actual_weight;
```

And setting the
`#[pallet::weight(0)]` above the pallet functions will make `call.get_dispatch_info().weight` to produce zero weight_fee.

Still, how can I get zero fee on MetaMask ?

Comment: Also would like to know this.
It does seem like the balance is checked in the `send_raw_transaction` EVM call [here](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/e8dbed108867e0bbdcc69c62ad488ec58f7aa1e7/primitives/evm/src/validation.rs#L139).
Want to know if there is a clean way to bypass this for certain precompiles.

Comment: I've the exact same question than you, how did you solved it in the end ?

Comment: not solved yet. what you see here is what I have so far... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work using this pallet config:

```
dynamicFee.targetMinGasPrice: Option<U256>
<none>

dynamicFee.minGasPrice: U256
1

baseFee.elasticity: Permill
0.00%

baseFee.baseFeePerGas: U256
0
```

**Note:** You have to set (Edit fee gas > Advanced) priority fee to 0 in metamask to get 0 fees.

Comment: Very good. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need to set `Pays::No` as return value for a feeless transaction. And for eip1559 at least `base_fee` is required for gas fee calculation. not sure fully understand what you mean and better add more detail here

Comment: please see my update above

Comment: can I cancel or remove that `base_fee` conditionally?

Comment: no,I mean the concept in eip1559, if with metamask normally `Max Priority fee` and `Max fee` are estimated based on the previous block’s history,`Base fee` is defined by the protocol and will be burnt. And I remember there is some default implementation in frontier