# How can one design and implement a fee rule?

Tags: transactions, substrate-node, fee, transaction-fees

I hope you are doing well!

How can one design and implement a fee rule on a substrate-based blockchain that is contingent on the transaction payment value?

I would like to create this fee rule based on the transaction value, where can I implement it?
Where can I use it,
Thank you for your help.

```
fn calculate_fee(value: Balance) -> Balance {
match value {
    0..=9 => 10000,
    10..=99 => 100000,
    100..=999 => 1000000,
    1000..=9999 => 10000000,
    10000..=99999 => 100000000,
    100000..=999999 => 1000000000,
    _ => 10000,
}
```

Comment: you can refer to https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/281/how-to-set-base-fee-and-len-fee-to-zero

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.